# GetOrgChart value not updating in jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, getorgchart

I am trying to update element in GetOrgChart and for that I am doing following

**Html**

```
<form id="one">
    <input type="text" name="aaa">
    <input type="text" name="bbb">
    <input type="submit" name='submitform' value="submit">
</form>
<br> 
<div id="people"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var oneForm = $("#one");
$("#people").getOrgChart({  
        clickEvent: function( sender, args ) {
            alert('args.id value outside validate '+args.id);

            oneForm.show();
            oneForm.validate({
                 // to add new area for team
                 rules: {
                     aaa: {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 3
                     },
                     bbb: {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 3
                     }
                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form) {
                     alert('args.id value inside validate '+args.id);
                     oneForm.hide();
                     return false;
                 }
             })

            //return false; //if you want to cancel the event
        },

         primaryColumns: ["Name", "Type"],
         linkType: "M",
         editable: false,
         zoomable: false,
         movable: true,
         gridView: true,

        dataSource: [
            { id: 1, parentId: -1, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Title: "CEO", Address: "MyAddress"},
            { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Title: "CTO", Phone: "+359 888 888 888"},
            { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson", Title: "CFO", Car: "BMW"}]
    });
```

Now just click on the chart element and than submit form you will see that

value of `args.id` not changing for `validate` function after first click

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6oehk11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem seems to be the scope of the variable "args".

It variables "born" in the anonymous function called on `clickEvent` and it exists only inside that event.

`submitHandler` is an handler managed by another inner function; so it is outside the scope of clickEvent.

So the solution is to declare (outside both functions a variables with a page scope).
Then, on click event, assegn it the `id` of `args`.
In this way you can use it inside submit event too.

In short (I commented with "//---" lines I added):

```
var oneForm = $("#one");
var globalArgsId; //--- Declare "global" variable
$("#people").getOrgChart({  
        clickEvent: function( sender, args ) {
            alert('args.id value outside validate '+args.id);
            globalArgsId = args.id; //--- Write value to global variable

            oneForm.show();
            oneForm.validate({
                 // to add new area for team
                 rules: {
                     aaa: {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 3
                     },
                     bbb: {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 3
                     }
                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form) {
                     alert('args.id value inside validate '+args.id);
                     alert('args.id value inside validate '+globalArgsId); //--- Access to global variable
                     oneForm.hide();
                     return false;
                 }
             })

            //return false; //if you want to cancel the event
        },

         primaryColumns: ["Name", "Type"],
         linkType: "M",
         editable: false,
         zoomable: false,
         movable: true,
         gridView: true,

        dataSource: [
            { id: 1, parentId: -1, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Title: "CEO", Address: "MyAddress"},
            { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Title: "CTO", Phone: "+359 888 888 888"},
            { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson", Title: "CFO", Car: "BMW"}]
    });
```

Hope it helps... :)